# String Manipulation and Comparisons

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I am trying to understand how R deals with string manipulation and comparisons.

To this end I have set up two data frames, one which is my raw data and the other which is my reference data to which I would like to compare. I'm trying to understand the different ways of comparing strings and how to compare data frames in general (it seems far easier in SQL where you can just use the key word contains).

For the example below, the first item is the reference data and the second is the raw data.

```
 grepl ("1845","UN1845")
```

Will return `TRUE`

```
 any ("1845"=="UN1845")
```

Will return `FALSE` (I assume here because the word has to match fully)

```
 is.element ("1845","UN1845")
```

Will return `FALSE` (same reason as the the any)

If I wanted to check the entire data reference table against each and every item in the raw table, how would I go about this?

From playing around I could do something like

```
grepl(Raw$Contents, Ref$desc)
```

Where the Raw data is basically strings and the ref data is strings. However when I run something like this, I get the message:

```
In grepl(Raw$Contents, MyCode$desc)
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I assume this is related to the fact that the table size for the reference table is different to the table I'm running comparisons against.

Sample data:

```
rawdata = data.frame(A=c("UN1845","FROZEN FOOD DRY ICE","LTD QTY8000"))
refdata = data.frame(A=c("1845","8000"))
```

Comment: It may be better to show some example data and expected result.  Perhaps, `grepl(paste(Raw$Contents, collapse="|"), Ref$desc)` works.

Comment: akrun already provided you with the correct solution. If this isn't it, please provide your desired output too.

Comment: Hi David, this is perfect...can you tell me how to accept your answer

Comment: It's not *my* answer it's akruns. @akrun please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: To clarify:  @akrun's solution puts a multiple-item "OR" into the regex, thus  sneaking around the 'one-pattern-only' limit on `grepl`  (I think)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft precisely, this solution is vectorized, though absolutely no need in `apply` loops. Though its kind of old trick which took me awhile to discover too.

Answer (score 0):

The errror message means:  your `pattern` argument has more than one element, but `grepl` and its family only accept one pattern at a time.  You will  have to loop (or `*apply`) over each pattern in your `refdata` collection.

EDIT: to clarify:  `grepl` only accepts one pattern, but if that pattern contains the complete search set, e.g. via the OR operator, `grepl` will function as desired.  thanks to David Arenburg for his comments.

Comment: Nope,  Not really... (I thought so too once though).

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you elaborate?  the help page is pretty explicit  " If a character vector of length 2 or more is supplied, the first element is used with a warning."

Comment: Checkout [@akruns comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232296/r-string-manipulation-comparisons/29232993?noredirect=1#comment46670648_29232296) and the [linked dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947587/matching-a-string-with-different-possibilities-using-grep).