# R: Can grep() include more than one pattern?

Tags: regex, r, grepl

For instance, in this example, I would like to remove the elements in `text` that contain `http` and `america`.

```
> text <- c("One word@", "112a httpSentenceamerica", "you and meamerica", "three two one")
```

Hence, I would use the logical operator, `|`.

```
> pattern <- "http|america"
```

Which works because this is considered to be one pattern.

```
> grep(pattern, text, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
[1] "One word@"     "three two one"
```

What if I have a long list of words that I would like to use in the pattern? How can I do it? I don't think I can keep on using the logical operators a lot of times.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try? You could paste the list together with "|" as separator.

Comment: We can use `paste` with `collapse="|"`

Comment: @akrun Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matching a string with different possibilities using grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947587/matching-a-string-with-different-possibilities-using-grep)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, as @akrun said:

```
text <- c("One word@", "112a httpSentenceamerica", "you and meamerica", "three two one")
pattern = c("http", "america")
grep(paste(pattern, collapse = "|"), text, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# [1] "One word@"     "three two one"
```

You wrote that your list of words is "long." This solution doesn't scale indefinitely, unsurprisingly:

```
long_pattern = paste(rep(pattern, 1300), collapse = "|")
nchar(long_pattern)
# [1] 16899
grep(long_pattern, text, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
# Error in grep(long_pattern, text, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE) :
```

But if necessary, you could MapReduce, starting with something along the lines of:

```
text[Reduce(`&`, Map(function(p) !grepl(p, text), long_pattern))]
# [1] "One word@"     "three two one"
```