# Str_detect with the pattern being a vector?

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a vector of approx. 77000 entries, and then another table. I went to filter the table so that I use `str_detect` with the pattern being any of the entries in the vector.

I tried to do `DF %>% filter(str_detect(Names, list))`.

So if the list was like `list <- c("apple", "pear", "orange")`
If the Names field contained apple OR pear OR orange (also AND) they would be the ones that would show up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching multiple patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6947587/matching-multiple-patterns)

Answer (score 7):

We can create a single string with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
DF %>% 
       filter(str_detect(Names, str_c("\\b(", str_c(list, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")))
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `str_c` over `paste`?

Comment: @camille. One advantage (depending on how you see it) is its behaviour when there is `NA` `str_c('a', NA)[1] NA
> paste0('a', NA)#
[1] "aNA"`
`