# filtering observations with multiple suffixes

Tags: r

As title suggests, I can´t figure out how to assign multiple suffixes, fx. 1,3,5

With just on suffix ("1), its no problem.

```
data[endsWith(as.character(data1$proc1), "1"), ]
```

I have tried as below, but it just doesn´t work.

```
suffix<-c("1","3","5")
data[endsWith(as.character(data1$proc1), suffix), ]

> show (data)
     proc1
1   KJAD30
2   KJJC00
3   KJFG50
4   KJAF30
5   KJAD30
6   KJAD11
7   KJAD30
8   KJAD30
9   KQBJ30
10  KJAD30
11  KJAB30
12  KJWC00
13  KJAA96
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947587/4137985

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `stringr` solution:

```
data %>% dplyr::filter(stringr::str_ends(proc1, paste0(suffix, "$", collapse = "|")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grepl`/`grep` to create a regex to select rows from the `data`

```
subset(data, grepl(paste0(suffix, "$", collapse = "|"), proc1))
```

With `grep`

```
data[grep(paste0(suffix, "$", collapse = "|"), data$proc1), ]
```

where the regex which we use to filter rows is

```
paste0(suffix, "$", collapse = "|")
#[1] "1$|3$|5$"
```